# Update the values of a dictionary checking if there are new values on a column of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a Pandas Dataframe like this:

```
    Source| MEDIA TYPE
    ___________________________
    AAA     | TV
    AAB     | CIN
    AAC     | RD
    AAD     | TV SOMETHING ELSE
```

And a dictionary with multiple values like this:

```
diz_media = {'TV':['TV', 'TV NEW MEDIA (TvAddressable)'], 'CIN':['CIN'], 'PRINT': ['PRINT'], 'RD':['RADIO', 'RD']}
```

I am trying to write a code that:

1. check if the values of the column 'MEDIA TYPE' are in the values of the dictionary 'diz_media'.
2. if they are not in the dictionary, the program ask me where (under which key) the new value should be added and wait for my input. (It would be nice to print the value in consideration here)
3. the program update the dictionary values according to the key I have written.

For instance, since the fourth value of the column ('TV SOMETHING ELSE') is not in the dict, the program should ask me under which key it is supposed to be. If I say, that it is one of the values of the key 'TV', the new values of tv should be: ['TV', 'TV NEW MEDIA (TvAddressable)', TV SOMETHING ELSE']

I know it's a bit long. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [DatFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```py
df['Media Type'].apply(lambda x: diz_media[input()].append(x) if x not in diz_media else None)
```

**Output:**

```
{'TV': ['TV', 'TV NEW MEDIA (TvAddressable)', 'TV SOMETHING ELSE'], 'CIN': ['CIN'], 'PRINT': ['PRINT'], 'RD': ['RADIO', 'RD']}
```

Using the function

```
def fun(x):
    if x not in diz_media:
        print("value is " + x)
        diz_media[input()].append(x)

df['Media Type'].apply(fun)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a possible way to also print the value before inserting the key?

Comment: @coelidonum yes, you can print the value, I have updated my answer check